# Why is there a @ character before the type property in .net core c#?

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Why is there a @ character before the type property while debugging ?

Below are the **ParentsId** class details used to pass the input parameters through API.

```
public class ParentsId
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

screen shot attached highlighted with color.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, before it was working (type) but from today suddenly it start reflecting like this (@type).

Comment: @CodeNotFound what is `type` a keyword for in C#? I've never seen anything about this, is this a new feature? It doesn't even show in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: @maksymiuk aahhh completely confuse it with `typeof`

Comment: Could you please tell me your visual studio version? VS2019 or VS 2022? Enterprise or else? Besides, I suggest you could try to update your VS version to see if this happen again or not.

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang, after updating Vs still i am still facing the same issue. 
VS details : Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.11.9.

Comment: Could you please share the codes which you have used for this line?